# Unable to get correct NSString Value in IF statement

Tags: variables, if-statement, nsstring

the IF statement shown below isn't working and i'm wondering if anyone knows why?

```
    NSString *tagString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_buttonTag];

if (tagString = @"%f",1) {
    NSLog(@"started with button TAG %@",_buttonTag);
```

My NSLog there DOES bring back the right variable each time. But my code does not meet the condition i think because the I'm not writing that if statement correctly. Hopefully this makes sense? Anyone know what i'm missing or doing wrong?

Basically, i want the variable in the string to equate to "1" (and other else if statements i have below this) so it runs my code in that particular If statement. I've tried %f, %d and %@ and nothing works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I had to convert the NSString to NSInteger like so:

```
NSString *tagString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_buttonTag];
NSInteger value = [tagString intValue];

if (value == 1) {
    NSLog(@"Tag 1 button TAG %d",value);
```

Works perfectly!!!